# Dart google_maps issue

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap-3, dart, dart-js-interop

i have a weird behavior of Google maps using dart !! [here](https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1/1901417_10203149397524400_1649460179_n.jpg)
as you see the link responsible for making th map appears is "Géolocalisation" until now i have no problem! but when i reclick, or when i visit another link then returning back to "Géo.." it gaves me [this](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/t1/1780878_10203149397204392_615595175_n.jpg)  and i really don't know what to do! this is my first try at GMap so i need a littel bit of help please.
i must mention that the page doesn't refresh when i click at the link it's only delets the old content from the container div then add the new elements also i must mention that i'm using bootstrap3,this is the code for the page géo

```dart
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
import '../view.dart';
import 'dart:html';
//view Map
class viewMap extends View{
  panelCoreBuilder(){
    //creating the container layout and it is a div row
    DivElement layout = new DivElement()..className="row";
    //adding a style element for the map element inside the container
    layout.children.add(new StyleElement()..text="#mapblock{margin: 0;padding: 0; height: 500px; width: 100%;"); 
    DivElement cellone = new DivElement()..className="col-md-3";
    //naming the block that contains the map
    DivElement celltow = new DivElement()..className="col-md-9"..id="mapblock";  
    //adding the cells to the layout 
    layout.children.addAll([cellone,celltow]);

    //creating the map
    visualRefresh = true;
    final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
    ..zoom = 8
    ..center = new LatLng(34.034453, -5.885925)
    ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
    final map = new GMap(celltow, mapOptions);
    //returning the layout to the MainContainer...
    return layout;
  }
}
```

so that's it i hope you can give me any solution ,hypotheses ,or even a hint
and if i fond the solution first i'll post it here!

Comment: Oky guys I tried to localize the problem and i did it, if you want to taste it your self you can download the code form [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ictaz68pe448ds5/GQrd_kNxuo), it happens when the map's loaded, when i delete the div contains the map somehow the navigator keeps saving a cache of the map (maybe!!) and when i reload it again the "things" there get a little messy! still i don't know what's the problem exactly!

Comment: another observation! when i resize the window it gets back to normal, how that even can be possible ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely that your `<div>` has an empty size (or not displayed) when the `new GMap` is called. The map is not aware of the `<div>` container resizing by default. You have to manually trigger a `resize` event when you display it on the screen with :

```dart
event.trigger(map, 'resize', []);
```

Comment: sorry but your solution didn't work! but please tell me if I'm wrong here i putted the event line directly under GMap is that correct ??

Comment: but it really did work on the example i gave already for localizing the problem !

Comment: You have to call this when the map container is attached to the dom and has the expected size.

Comment: so is it a good idea to make this in a future function ??
ex: drowMap(Mydiv).then((map)=>event.trigger(map, 'resize', []));

Comment: It really depends on your code. You can also use [Timer.run](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-async.Timer@id_run) or something like that.

Comment: friend Alexander i made the map function in a future as i said and it worked just fine thank you for all your help, your line saved me :D even i still don't know what it's actually means hhh! thank you anyway!